# Issue nginx redirect and delete referrer information

Tags: nginx

We are checking for a couple of spammy referrers in our nginx configuration and want to redirect their requests to our homepage. The problem is that nginx is passing along the original referer as part of the redirect, and so when the redirected request comes in, the bad referer is still present and nginx issues another redirect. Example:

Bad site links to `example.com/page.html`. We redirect that request to `example.com` because we don't want the bad referers to send traffic to our pages. The problem is that when nginx receives the request for `example.com`, that bad referer is still present and so nginx issues another redirect, and so on to infinity. How can I clear the original referer when issuing a redirect from nginx?

Here is the relevant block that we're using. We populate `$bad_referer` with a `map` in the http section of our config.

```
if ($bad_referer) {
  return 302 http://www.example.com;
}
```

Comment: Would using a permanent redirect (`return 301`) fix the problem?

Comment: My research indicates that most browsers still pass the referrer with a 301 as well.

Comment: That may be true. My understanding is that the permanent redirect informs the browser to retain the permanent redirect destination, but I haven't experimented with it.

Comment: Ah. I will try, but I'm guessing nginx is going to see the retained referrer and just issue another redirect again and again infinitely. Will report back.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Still got the infinite redirect.

Comment: got updated Chrome, 301 wont pass it (im redirecting http to https)